# Correct integral to compute volume of a solid

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I want to compute the volume obtained by rotating the bounded region of $y=3-x^2$, $y=2x$, $x \leq 0$ around the $y$-axis. I want to use the cylindrical shell method, so my integral is:

$\displaystyle V=2\pi\int_{-3}^0 x(3-x^2-2x) \,\mathrm{d}x$

However, my answer is $\displaystyle -\frac{45\pi}{2}$. It is a negative number. I don't think it is correct because when I try to compute the area between $y=0$ and $y=x^2-4$, I still have a positive number even though the curve is under the $x-axis$, so I think there must be $-x$ or reversing the limit of integration.

What would be the correct way to set up this integral without using the absolute value.

Thank you.

PS: This is relating to section 5.2 and 5.3 in Stewart Calculus book.

Comment: You just need to change $x$ to $-x$, since $r(x)=0-x=-x$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.